# How do I change Jenkins build folder? (SVN_REVISION instead of BUILD_ID)

Tags: jenkins

How do I change the build folder Jenkins use? Jenkins uses BUILD_ID (timestamp) to create folders inside \builds\ so they look like "2012-12-14_10-17-15". Is there a way to use the SVN_REVISION instead?

Maybe I should just create a shortcut on C:\Builds\ using SVN_REVISION that points to jenkins\jobs\job_name\builds\build_id, but I wish there was another way to do this.

Comment: Before you do that, consider how you are going to handle the case where more than one build is made for a given SVN revision. If you allow manually starting a build, it is likely to happen at some point.

Comment: I agree with @jwernerny. This is internal to Jenkins and you should not be touching it at all. There are reasons why it is the way it is (such as the multiple builds having the same revision number). Additionally, existing functionality and plugins may break if you change Jenkins internal structure. Maybe if you would explain *why* you want to do this, then we could give you a better alternative.

Comment: I've configured Jenkins to build automatically. It'll only build when changes are detected. Maybe the folders could use BUILD_ID+SVN_REVISION. That way I'd have both informations and would avoid the problem of 2 builds having the same revision.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying Jenkins internals, you could add another step at the end of your project that dumps the SVN_REVISION and BUILD_ID information somewhere, maybe into a CSV file depending on what you are trying to do. You could even add a step to create shortcuts for you.

Comment: My problem is that the testers are used to just accessing /build/svn_revision on the old (manual) method of building. I've been told it should stay that way. Right now I have something set up that moves the build to the old folder structure. But Jenkins won't be able to delete older builds automatically. I'm thinking shortcuts (everybody uses windows) is the way to go.